# What is the correct way to set up apache RewriteMap to pull from a Database? (PHP/APACHE/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, rewritemap

I am trying to set up clean URL's on my small web app. Right now the URL's look like:

**http://www.mysite.com/productinfo.php?product=19**

I want them to be:

**http://www.mysite.com/productinfo.php?product=Shoes**

How would I write both the RewriteMap and the PHP script to pull the *title* column in the database and inject it in the URL in place of the product ID and forward visitors on their merry way?

Comment: Perhaps what you really want to do is something more like `http://www.mysite.com/product/info/9/shoes`?

Comment: Yes actually I would. I guess I was trying to simplify the question as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case, it doesn't look like you're going to need a URL rewrite, since you're just using the same `$_GET` variable.

Just check for the right title in the database when you interpret `$_GET['product']`, and find the right product id from there. I don't think you need Apache to solve this problem.

Comment: @A Stubbs, you need to decide what you are trying to do here.  If you want SEO-style URIs then you need your app to decode `/product/Shoes` and HTTP server isn't going to help here.

Comment: That's why I did a +1, but just paraphrasing for the OP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple rewrite like this -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/info/.*$ productinfo.php [NC,L]
```

in an htaccess file, vhost or other config and then use -

```
$var = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

to retrieve the original request. This is only a very simple example but it should get you moving in the right direction.